# Installing Ubuntu via a USB stick

Tags: system-installation

I have decided to try Ubuntu because 1)my friend keeps saying how good it is and how much windows suck, and 2)my OEM windows stuffed up. I was wondering if there is a way to install Ubuntu to my desktop using the usb stick

Comment: please google before asking questions. This is the first google result for your question. [create USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and [install ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you need to download the live iso first.
Then you would need to download the Pendrive usb installer, or yumi, they run under windows and are quite good.
Start Pendrive "Burn" the Iso-file to your USB-stick, it takes some time!
Leave the Usb-stick in your computer and reboot.
During boot select boot from USB (Pressing F12 usually bringes up a boot menu)
Ubuntu should now boot from your USB-stick (thats why its called a live ISO)
Check that you have a good working system!
If satisfyed go through the install options, else try another flaver of Ubuntu.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) and [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) for detailed instructions.